# findoneandupdate and duplicate error 11000

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

hello i have a problem running my code because it say E11000 duplicate key error collection

```
router.put('/:city/edit',isAdminCheck, async function(req,res){
var query = req.params.city;
var update = {region:req.body.region,country:req.body.country,image:req.body.image,flag:req.body.flag,languages:req.body.languages,currencies:req.body.currencies,city:req.body.city};
CityList.findOneAndUpdate(query,update,{upsert:true}, function(error){
    if(error){
        if(error.code === 11000){
            CityList.findOneAndUpdate(query,update,{upsert:true}, function(error){
                if(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }else{
                    res.redirect("/" + req.params.cty);
                }
            })
        }
    }else{
        res.redirect("/" + req.params.city);
    }
})

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not correct. It should be this

```
var query = {city: req.params.city};
```

And you are doing a same update twice. You should only call it once.

```
CityList.findOneAndUpdate(query,update,{upsert:true}, function(error){
    if(error){
        // handle error
        }
    }else{
        res.redirect("/" + req.params.city);
    }
})
```